# How to install FastQC 0.11.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

When I install fastqc from the repositories with the command:

```
  sudo apt-get install fastqc
```

the version 0.11.2 is installed. However there is a newer version here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fastqc

which is 0.11.5.

How can I upgrade to the latest version on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could update it like this:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/fastqc_0.11.5+dfsg-3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i fastqc_0.11.5+dfsg-3_all.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```